# jCarousel: Get the filename (path) of the image which is currently shown (only one at a time)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, jcarousel

I have an enlarge-button near the slider. Now I want to change the `href` attribute of the anchor for my fancybox. For this reason I need to get the current image of the jCarousel. Since the file path is always the same I wouldn't need the path but if I get path + filename it would be also OK. I think I have to traverse the DOM and set the href attribute of the anchor.

This is what I have so far:

```
function getCurrImage(carousel, state){
   /*alert(carousel.first);*/
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        scroll:1,
        'itemLoadCallback': getCurrImage 
    });
});
```

This gives me the index of the current picture in the slider (e.g. 1). Also this function is called multiple times (don't know why). Here is my pseudo-code:

```
var imagepath = jQuery.find(".jcarousel-item:nth-child(carousel.first)".a.img.attr("src");
jQuery.find(a.enlarge).attr("href",imagepath);
```

Would this work?

**Edit:**

This seems to work:

```
function getCurrImage(carousel, state){
    var currentImage = carousel.first-1;
    var path = jQuery(".jcarousel-item").eq(currentImage).children('a').attr("href");
    jQuery("A.enlarge").attr("href", path);
}
```

But my idea didn't worked as expected. Normally I have three items in my gallery. Now I have four (duplicate content) in the fancybox and I'm on the last position. I hoped to have only three elements and the one which is currently shown in jCarousel should be enlarged in fancybox. So I have to look for another possibility...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood what you mean, this should work:

```
function getCurrImage(carousel, state){
    var currentImage = carousel.first;
    var path = $(".jcarousel-item").eq(currentImage).attr("src");
    $("A.enlarge").attr("href", path);
}
```

Comment: I get path is undefined. I think the reason is that `jcarousel-item` has the child elements `a` and `img`. Only the last one (img) has the `src` attribute.

Comment: That sounds the likely cause of the error then. Could you post the HTML that's generated by the plugin in your OP.

Comment: Now I got this running (see my edited question). But it doesn't work as desired. Do you have an idea for that? I want to have a button which enlarges the current image in jcarousel. For the enlargment I would like to use fancybox.

Comment: `$.fancybox.pos` could be the right thing. But how to use that function?

Comment: I have opened a new question. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272719/link-should-open-fancybox-fancybox-pos-with-the-help-of-the-click-function)