# Link should open fancybox ($.fancybox.pos) with the help of the click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, fancybox

I want a button which opens the fancybox rel-group with a certain picture. I'm not quite sure if this works but I'll give it a try. My problem is that I want to execute jQuery if the user clicks on a link. This is the code I have

```
var js = "jQuery.fancybox.pos("+currentImage+");";
// create a new function from the "js" string
var newclick = new Function(js);

jQuery("a.enlarge").click(newclick);
```

The code is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/826697/426227). I hope that 
`jQuery.fancybox.pos(2)` works. But currently I'm not getting the click function to work. What I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**

My current setup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var currentImage = 0;

  function getCurrImage(carousel, state){
     currentImage = carousel.first-1;

     jQuery("a.enlarge").click(function() {
       alert(currentImage);   
       jQuery.fancybox.pos(currentImage);
     });
   }

   jQuery.noConflict();

   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
           scroll:1,
           'itemLoadCallback': getCurrImage 
       }); 
       jQuery('a[rel=example_group]').fancybox({
           'transitionIn': 'none',
           'transitionOut': 'none'
       });
   });
</script>
```

`jQuery.fancybox.pos(currentImage);` doesn't work. `currentImage` seems to be correct, but the alert pops up 4 times if the button was clicked 4 times. That means:

click 1: currentImage=0
click 2: currentImage=1, currentImage=1
click 3: currentImage=2, currentImage=2, currentImage=2
click 4: currentImage=3, currentImage=3, currentImage=3, currentImage=3

**Update:**

New try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var currentImage = 0;

function openfancy(){
   jQuery.fancybox.pos(currentImage);
}

  function getCurrImage(carousel, state){
     currentImage = carousel.first-1;

     jQuery("a.enlarge").unbind("click", openfancy);
     jQuery("a.enlarge").bind("click", openfancy);
   }

   jQuery.noConflict();

   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
           scroll:1,
           'itemLoadCallback': getCurrImage 
       }); 
       jQuery('a[rel=example_group]').fancybox({
           'transitionIn': 'none',
           'transitionOut': 'none'
       });
   });
</script>
```

`jQuery.fancybox.pos(currentImage);` still doesn't work. Is there any chance? Perhaps its because I have multiple fancyboxes on that page? I also tried it with `jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox.pos(currentImage);` but I get the error message that it is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pos` function never worked. So I took the idea of a deleted answer to use the click-function. If a user clicks on my link it should simulate the click on the picture in the gallery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentImage = 0;

    function getCurrImage(carousel, state){
        currentImage = carousel.first-1;
    }

    /*jQuery.noConflict();*/

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#fancycarousel').jcarousel({
            scroll:1,
            'itemLoadCallback': getCurrImage 
        }); 
        jQuery('a[rel=example_group]').fancybox({
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none'
        });
        jQuery('#enlarge').click(function(){
            jQuery(".jcarousel-item").eq(currentImage).children("a").click();
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

I needed hours to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

Use an anonymous function:

```
jQuery("a.enlarge").click(function() {
  jQuery.fancybox.pos(currentImage);
});
```

I'm not sure what `currentImage` is, though.

---

Try this code as well:

```
var currentImage = 0;

$('#your_carousel').jcarousel({
  itemLoadCallback: function(carousel, state) {
    currentImage = carousel.first;
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked. `currentImage` is a number which comes from the current presented image of jCarousel. My anchor looks like this `<a class="enlarge" href="javascript:;">`. OK an `alert` does the job. But `fancybox.pos` seems not to work. Do you know how to use this function?

Comment: See my edit. I'm not going to code it all for you, so dome research yourself.

Comment: I already had the code you posted. My problem currently is that I haven't found out how to use the `jQuery.fancybox.pos` function ...